# Chances of picking a person from a company - 2 Different answers?

Tags: probability, statistics

First I must sorry in advance, because this question sounds really basic, but couldn't find anything on the internet as I don't know how to phrase this question into a simple google query.. if this is a duplicate I would highly appreciate if you could send a link to a similar question. Sorry again!

---

This is a theoretical question, so I am making this situation up.

Let's say that we have a company which consists of $10,000$ workers, we'll call this company $A$.
Then we have $6,000$ people from company $B$, then $2,000$ from $C$ and so on. The numbers don't need to follow a special rule, except:

- $A$ has the largest amount of workers (In this case $10,000$)
- The sum of the workers of all the companies $B, C, D, \dots $ must be larger than $A$'s.

We enclose all of the workers of all these companies in a huge room.
Now, "special sense" of probability and statistics (AKA intuition) says that if we take big tweezers and choose a random worker, the probability of him being from company $A$ is the greatest.

**However**, it doesn't make sense if I think about it longer, because the question is if the worker is from $A$ or ***not*** $A$, and say the chances of him is $x$ then the chances of $\bar{x}$ is bigger as the sum of all the non-$A$ workers is larger...

Which way of thinking is correct? It got me very confused

---

In order to showcase those intuitions I will present an example.
Say for example, we have this set of data:

1. $A$ has $10,000$ workers
2. $B$ has $5,000$
3. $C$ has $6,000$
4. $D$ has $7,000$

Clearly it follows the rule that $\#A > \#\text{not}A$ and the sum of all the workers from all the companies which are not $A$ is larger than $10,000$.

What would be the probability to choose a person from $A$?

$$P(A) =  \frac{10000}{10000+5000+6000+7000} = \frac{10}{28} \\ P(\bar{A}) = 1 - \frac{10}{28} = \frac{18}{28}$$

Clearly:
$$ P(A) < P(\bar{A})$$

So, which statement is correct? Statistically speaking if we choose a random worker, it would be $A$'s as there are more workers from this company than any other company, but the probability of choosing ***not*** $A$ proved to be larger, from the example above..

Comment: i don't see any ambiguity here.  If company $X$ is not $A$, then $P(A)>P(X)$.  However $P(A)<\sum_{X\neq A}P(X)$.  That's all.

Comment: @lulu But intuitively,  if you were asked "which worker would it be?" you would say $A$, however probability says the other way.. no?

Comment: This comes up all the time in sports better.  One horse will be the favorite in some upcoming race, but that doesn't mean that there is a greater than $\frac 12$ chance that this horse will win.

Comment: If I have to pick one company, then of course I'll take the largest, but I won't feel very confident there because the other companies combined are much greater.

Comment: But that is not statistically the same isn't it? because what has "which horse is likely to win" has to do with the actual race, as for my examples which have a concrete example with real numbers? (I am not a math wiz and especially not a probability one, so I am asking this out of curiosity)

Comment: I don't see any difference between the horse question and this, it's just probability.

Comment: If you want a different analogy, say you choose a random American.  If I said "guess which city this person is from." you'd have to guess NY as that's the biggest by far.  But you will almost certainly be wrong because, collectively, the other cities dwarf NY.

Comment: @lulu I think the question is the tricky part. I will phrase it again. If you were asked "choosing a random worker from the data set above, which person is likely to come out" then saying "worker from A" is a reasonable answer? or "not a person from A is likely" more reasonable?

Comment: Illustrate with a simpler example.  Suppose that $A,B,C$ have chances $40$%, $30$%, $30$% respectively.  Then, $A$ is the most likely of the $3$, at $40$%, yet at the same time, the chance of $A$ not being picked is $(100\% - 40\%) = 60\%$.

Comment: Again, if you are forced to guess a single company, of course you choose the biggest.  But that does not mean that you are likely to be correct, just that it is the best answer out of a bunch of bad options.

Comment: This sort of thing frequently happens in elections with more than two candidates. A candidate who has received more than half of all votes has received a "majority" of the votes; while a candidate who has received more votes than any other candidate has received a "plurality" of the votes. Majority implies plurality; but not vice versa.

Comment: YOu can make a more extreme example.  Suppose I have $10^9+1$ pieces of paper in a pile.  On them are written the numbers $\{1,2,\cdots, 10^9\}$ but I have added a duplicate number $1$.  If I draw one at random at ask you to guess, you'd really want to chose $1$, as that is twice as likely as any other guess.  But twice a number  near $0$ is still near $0$.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you for your time and patience everyone. I would still be highly appreciative if someone could post an answer with some more interesting insights or ideas. Thank you again

Comment: I mean, statistically speaking can I say that $1$ is more LIKELY than any different number? (this is what confuses me, the word likely is vague for me) @lulu

Comment: it is certainly more likely than any other guess.  the probability that $1$ is correct is $\frac 2{10^9+1}$ while every other guess has probability $\frac {1}{10^9+1}$.